# How to write first 7 entites in one json file and next 7 entites in second file until the end using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to generate output files in such a way, first 7 entities into first json file, and next 7 entities into second json file, so on until the end.

```
data_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tables/'
for i, data_item in enumerate(data):
    with open(data_path + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(simplejson.dumps({'entities': [data]}, indent=4, ignore_nan=True))
```

My script above, generates 1 entity for 1 Json file, but I really need 7 entities for each output Json file.

Comment: To make clear: you want items 0..6 in first file, 7..13 in the second, and so on?  What will you name these files?

Comment: That open `str` is blah.  Use f-strings: `open(f'{data_path}{i}.json', 'w')`

Comment: Yes Scott, your understanding is right. 0..6 in first file and 7..13 in second file. I will name the files as 0.json and 1.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only getting 1 entity per JSON file because you're only iterating 1 entity at a time

```
for i, data_item in enumerate(data):
```

Also, based on the code in the question, I'm assuming you're iterating a files in a directory (although as written, you'll just be iterating characters in your string, but I digress).

To get the 7 entities per JSON you're looking for, you'll need to create that list per iteration, or iterate the list in chunks of 7 (I recommend the `chunks` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/4739755)).

```
data_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tables/'
# Assume data is a list of filenames in a directory

# In this case, data_item will be a list of *up to* 7 entities
for i, data_item in enumerate(chunks(data, 7)):
    with open(f'{data_path}{i}.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(simplejson.dumps({'entities': data_item}, indent=4, ignore_nan=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I am getting below error.---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2ffadf7595b6> in <module>
      3 
      4 # In this case, data_item will be a list of *up to* 7 entities
----> 5 for i, data_item in enumerate(chunks(data, 7)):
      6     with open(f'{data_path}{i}.json', 'w') as outfile:
      7         outfile.write(simplejson.dumps({'entities': data_item}, indent=4, ignore_nan=True))

NameError: name 'chunks' is not defined

Comment: You need to include the `chunks` method from the linked SO post in my answer.